# Can't access a wcf service from Windows 7, but I can from XP or Vista

Tags: wcf, windows-7, http-status-code-404, service-reference

I have a WCF service running on Server 2008 standard that works fine when calling from an XP client or Vista.  I can compile the program (using VS2010, WPF) from an XP system and it will run fine on Vista or XP.  If I try to run on a Windows 7, no luck.  I also installed VS2010 on the Windows 7 system and try to update the service reference in the project, I get the same error.
"The document at the url http://192.168.0.242/AuthorizationService.svc was not recognized as know document type... - The request failed wit HTTP status 404...

Is there a difference in Windows 7 when creating and using a service reference than XP or Vista?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/06/26/wcf-add-reference-error-the-document-at-the-url-was.aspx

Comment: Yes. I also verified the config file has <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />

Comment: Is 192.168.0.242 your Windows 2008 Server?

Comment: yes. just using it for testing and development.